# kernel headers linux not found

Tags: kali-linux, linux-headers

I can't get past the :

```
apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.18.0-kali2-amd64
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.18.0-kali2-amd64'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.18.0-kali2-amd64'
```

I checked my sources.list which contains:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

`uname -r` returns:

```
4.18.0-kali2-amd64
```

And when I run `apt-cache search linux-image` I get:

```
linux-headers-4.18.0-kali3-amd64 - Header files for Linux 4.18.0-kali3-amd64
linux-headers-4.18.0-kali3-cloud-amd64 - Header files for Linux 4.18.0-kali3-cloud-amd64
linux-headers-4.18.0-kali3-rt-amd64 - Header files for Linux 4.18.0-kali3-rt-amd64
linux-image-4.18.0-kali3-amd64 - Linux 4.18 for 64-bit PCs
linux-image-4.18.0-kali3-amd64-dbg - Debug symbols for linux-image-4.18.0-kali3-amd64
linux-image-4.18.0-kali3-cloud-amd64 - Linux 4.18 for x86-64 cloud
linux-image-4.18.0-kali3-cloud-amd64-dbg - Debug symbols for linux-image-4.18.0-kali3-cloud-amd64
linux-image-4.18.0-kali3-rt-amd64 - Linux 4.18 for 64-bit PCs, PREEMPT_RT
linux-image-4.18.0-kali3-rt-amd64-dbg - Debug symbols for linux-image-4.18.0-kali3-rt-amd64
linux-image-amd64 - Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package)
linux-image-amd64-dbg - Debugging symbols for Linux amd64 configuration (meta-package)
linux-image-cloud-amd64 - Linux for x86-64 cloud (meta-package)
linux-image-cloud-amd64-dbg - Debugging symbols for Linux cloud-amd64 configuration (meta-package)
linux-image-rt-amd64 - Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package), PREEMPT_RT
linux-image-rt-amd64-dbg - Debugging symbols for Linux rt-amd64 configuration (meta-package)
linux-image-4.18.0-kali2-amd64 - Linux 4.18 for 64-bit PCs
```

I'm running kali on an external SSD with live persistence.

I did update and upgrade.

Comment: No, I already tried the solutions offered there...

Comment: You should reread it. The values have changed but the problem is the same. You have to upgrade your kernel to -kali3, for which headers are available.

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade your kernel package first, as you seem to have 4.18.0-kali2 installed but only 4.18.0-kali3 is available in the package repository at this time.

At the time you installed the kernel, the current version was 4.18.0-kali2. This is the risk of running a distribution that doesn't guarantee that versions remain available for a long period of time.

Note that even after installing the new kernel version, until you reboot into that kernel, `$(uname -r)` will still return the old version number.

Comment: Then you need to get an updated live image on your USB.